# How to make virtual Joystick on Android to run PC game?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to develop a  virtual joystick on android   to control PC game using Bluetooth. I don't know how to develop this project. Can anyone suggest how to complete this project step by step?

Answer (score 0):

There are already applications like this, for example https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.negusoft.ugamepad&hl=ru

If you still want to develop it, you should read about bluetooth protocol and make a simple application interface.